# Adsense in a post that has an iframe

Tags: google-adsense, iframe

I have pondered weather it is permissible by Google to display Adsense ads on a page that has had an iframe forever.

I have a blog post that displays Google Adsense ads, an embedded contact form from a third party, and my own YouTube video using an iframe.

Is this violating Google's policy in anyway?

Comment: Unfortunately, as far as I can see, "yes". It violates g's policy

Comment: Can you please elaborate on that because I got two different answers here. Goyllo made a good point that Dsiqus is embedded on sites using an iframe. I just want to be sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It is totally OK.**

Google own product Blogger using Google plus comments in iframe. Disqus and Facebook also display comments in iframe. **It violates only, when ads shown under iframe**

Comment: Thanks man. I never looked at it that way. I really appreciate you answering my question. Gob bess

Comment: I'm glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand:

There is a main website A (whose address is seen by the visitor, in the browser), and the AdSense code can only be placed directly in that website A.

If there is a website B, that is inserted into A using iFrame, and B contains AdSense code, Google considers it invalid, and you will not get any money when somebody clicks on the ad (even though the ad inside B is always displayed).

It does not matter, if A and B have the same or a different owner, or if they are both on the same domain. The ad inside B is simply "an ad placed in an iframe", which is against AdSense policy.